# Gradle : How to bump transitive dependency version which is coming from plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a huge java multimodule application which uses gradle to manage build and dependencies.
In one of the modules let's say module1 the project is using [gretty](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty) plugin

- module1/build.gradle

---

```
plugins{
    id 'org.gretty'
}
```

gretty is having a transitive dependency on `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3`

I want to bump the logback version to the latest. For that I have tried below solutions

```
dependencies {
    // 1 try
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6'

    // 2nd try
    implementation ('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6') {
        force = true
    }

    // 3rd try

    constraints {
        implementation('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6') {
            because 'some xyz reason'
        }
    }
}
```

But none of this is having any impact on logback version. Need some suggestion now

Answer (score 0):

What you have done so far is for *application* dependencies, not *build* dependencies. To change or add additional dependencies to the build itself, use the `buildscript` block. So for you case, to bring in a more recent version of Logback:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6'
    }
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies

You can then invoke the `buildEnvironment` task to view the dependencies of the build.